# JS flatten array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is possible to make JSON array more flatten?

For example I have this kind of JSON. How can I merge object starting by { into one object flat object? "row" should be converted info "name": "Row1"

```
[
  [
    "Row1",
    {
      "TOI": 25116,
      "g": 8,
      "r_g": 0,
      "o_g": 0,
      "f_g": 0,
      "sg": 6
    }
  ]
]
```

This is what I have expecting:

```
[
   {
      "name": "Row1",
      "TOI": 25116,
      "g": 8,
      "r_g": 0,
      "o_g": 0,
      "f_g": 0,
      "sg": 6
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share more details about what out is expected?

Comment: `let res = arr.map(el => { el[1].name = el[0]; return el[1] })`

Comment: @Ashvin777 added to post

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your problem

```js
let table = [
  [
    "Row1",
    {
      "TOI": 25116,
      "g": 8,
      "r_g": 0,
      "o_g": 0,
      "f_g": 0,
      "sg": 6
    }
  ], [
    "Row2",
    {
      "TOI": 25116,
      "g": 8,
      "r_g": 0,
      "o_g": 0,
      "f_g": 0,
      "sg": 6
    }
  ]
];

table = table.map(row => {
   return {
     "name": row[0],
     ...row[1]
   }
});

console.log(table);
```